# Proper quote escaping/preserving in bash function

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

The following command with 2 parameters does what I need if I enter it in a terminal:

```
mycommand 'string that includes many spaces and double quotes' 'another string that includes many spaces and double quotes'
```

Now I move the above to the bash script.

```
C=mycommand 'string that includes many spaces and double quotes'
function f {
 $C $1
}
# let's call it
f 'another string that includes many spaces and double quotes'
```

Obviously this is not going to produce the same result, or any useful result. But I can not come up with the correct way of preserving and/or properly escaping quotes, spaces and keeping number of actual parameters that **mycommand** sees as 2.

I use GNU bash version 3.2.57 on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you quote each parameter, it will be properly handled as a positional parameter:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
f() {
  echo "function was called with $# parameters:"
  while ! [[ -z $1 ]]; do
    echo "  '$1'"
    shift
  done
}
f "param 1" "param 2" "a third parameter"
$ ./459461.sh
function was called with 3 parameters:
  'param 1'
  'param 2'
  'a third parameter'
```

Note however that the containing (i. e. outermost) quotes are *not* part of the parameter itself.  Let's try a slightly different invocation of the function:

```
$ tail -n1 459461.sh
f "them's fightin' words" '"Holy moly," I shouted.'
$ ./459461.sh
function was called with 2 parameters:
  'them's fightin' words'
  '"Holy moly," I shouted.'
```

Observe that the `'`s in the output surrounding the reproduced parameters are coming from the `echo` statement in the function, and not the parameters themselves.

To dress up your example code to be more quote-aware, we can do this:

```
C=mycommand
f() {
  $C "unchanging first parameter" "$1"
}
# let's call it
f 'another string that includes many spaces and double quotes'
```

Or this:

```
C=mycommand
f() {
  $C "$1" "$2"
}
# let's call it
f 'Some string with "quotes" that are scary' 'some other "long" string'
```